# how can I select from list with array condition

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, arraylist

I want to select from List with array condition

I want to do that

```
var res = from r in liste where r.id1==array1 ||r.id2==arry1  select r;
```

the array1 and array2 are arrays contains ids

how can I do that

Comment: Your query doesn't include an `array2`.  Did you mean to have `r.id2==array2`?

Comment: in the fact the array1 and the array2 are List<int> contain the ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want items in `list` that have an `id1` contained in `array1` or an `id2` contained in `array2` you can do this:

```
var res = from r in list where array1.Contains(r.id1) || array2.Contains(r.id2) select r;
```

EDIT: if `id1` and `id2` are nullable `int`s:

```
var res = from r in list 
          where r.id1.HasValue && array1.Contains(r.id1.Value) || 
                r.id2.HasValue && array2.Contains(r.id2.Value) 
          select r;
```

Comment: +1 but while I do that for list<int> in place array  display this error
The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>.Contains(int)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @BilalELbakhti: what is the type of r.id1 and r.id2?

Comment: var res = from r in list where arrayList.Contains(r.id1) || arrayList.Contains(r.id2) select r; 
the type off array1 and raay2  are List<int>

Comment: @BilalELbakhti: Sorry, but I do not understand well, please can add the definitions of `array1`, `array2`, `list` and the model (where id1 and id2 are defined).

Comment: the defintion of the array1 and array2

      static List<int> array1 = null;
        static List<int> array2=null;

 array1 = new List<int>();

            for (int i = 0; i < selectedRows.Length; i++)
            {
                array1.Add(Convert.ToInt32(GridLook_fa.GetRowCellValue(selectedRows[i], GridLook_fa.Columns["Id"])));

            }
and the sema for array2

Comment: and the list is List<T>

Comment: yes, but what is the type of id1 and id2? are `int`, `int?`, or `long` or `decimal`, or anything else?

Comment: the type of id1 and id2 are int int

Answer (score 1):

The Where function has also an index parameter:

```
   var res = liste.Where((r, i) => r.id1 == array1[i] || r.id2 == array1[i]);
```

Comment: the list contain object like that 

liste<Car> and I want to select all item of this object whith condtiion

Comment: My code returns a IEnumerable<Car>. If you want a list just add a ".ToList()" at the end.

Comment: what if I replace the array1 and array2 wiith lis<int> ?

Comment: Doesn't matter. The result will be the same. But my approach will only work if all the arrays and lists has the same size. Arturo Menchanca's code works also with unordered arrays and arrays with different sizes.

Comment: but return this error 
Error 1 Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int?' and 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>'

Comment: Then you should tell us the types of those objects. What type is id1 and what type does the array elements have?